# How docker named volume works?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am new to docker and volumes and is confused about how named volumes are working. I have two scenarios in which I want to know how the named volumes will work

**First Scenario**
I have to setup two projects with docker and both have separate databases. Now how the database volumes will be mapped with `/var/lib/mysql`? Does it maintain separate data based on db name?

**Second Scenario**
I have two services using same named volume. In both the services, the path of container mapped to the named volume is different. How this will work?

```
services:
  s1:
     volume:
       - vol:/var/lib/s1
  s2:
     volume:
       - vol:/var/lib/s2
volumes:
 vol:
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `docker-compose`, it does some things for you. If your composed "project name" is `project_a`, the docker-compose `vol` volume will be named `project_a_vol`. Verify this by running `docker volume ls`. By a "composed project name" I mean the name of the project which usually equals to the name of the directory in which the `docker-compose` was run, or custom one if the `--project-name` parameter was set (eg. `docker-compose --project-name xxx up`)

I assume you're using the default docker volume filesystem storage driver. A named volume is nothing more than a directory inside the `/var/lib/docker/volumes` folder (try it `sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker/volumes`). By mounting a volume using `vol:/var/lib/s1` you tell docker to synchronize directories:

Local `/var/lib/docker/volumes/project_a_vol` with container directory `/var/lib/s1`.

If you compose your services this way:

```
services:
  s1:
     volumes:
       - vol:/var/lib/s1
  s2:
     volumes:
       - vol:/var/lib/s2
```

The same directory will be mounted to 2 services: `s1` and `s2` and you most probably will have a problem because 2 services will try to read & write to the same directory at the same time. Unless those services can handle such case.

It's better to have separate volumes though. In such case a volume for one service can be purged leaving the other one intact.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to your questions. 
**First Scenario** : Two docker containers with a DB each.
 - For this scenario since the databases are different, they run on their own container space. 
 - You can create a [Docker Volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) or use [Docker bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to attach disk to your Database `/var/lib/mysql' 
  - If you use volumes, you create one volume per database and the data are isolated.

  - If you use bind mounts, make sure you mount different disk locations, if you use same location, the second database container data will overwrite the first database data.

**Second Scenario** : As per this scenario, since the Volume label is same, the second coming up service data would replace the already running Service data every time the services start.